# Access: Format Date "\Www\_yyyy"

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using `Format(Date, "\Www\_yyyy")` to have this result.

[image]

I would like to keep 2 digits also for the first 9 weeks, for example: `W04_2019`. But what I get with this formula is:

[image]

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. Seems like you must build it yourself:

```
Format(DatePart("ww", Date), "\W00") & Format(Date, "\_yyyy")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use two `Format` for week number and connect year string with `&`

```
Format(Format(Date,"ww"),' \W00')  & Format(Date, "\_yyyy")
```